# I want to write regex that starts and end with numbers and letters only but can have special character hyphen, underscore and space in between

Tags: regex

I tried writing this: ^[A-Za-z0-9-*][A-Za-z0-9-* ]{1,30}$
But the regex should not start and end with a special character or space.

Sample values It should allow:

EcoLight

Eco-Light

Eco_Light

Eco Light

Eco Light 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use:

```
^(?!.{31})[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kvj0pP/1). The negative lookahead will prevent over 30 characters while the non-capture group allows for multiple groups of characters that are delimited through any of the characters in the class `[ _-]`.

Answer (score 0):

If the regex pattern ends with a letter or digit then it won't end with something else

```
^[A-Za-z0-9-][A-Za-z0-9_ -]{0,29}[A-Za-z0-9]$
```